# How different ways can a family of 4 pose in pictures with no restrictions

Tags: linear-algebra

Mom and dad can be in back or front. 2 kids can be in back and front. Mom and sister in front or back dad and son in front of back.

Comment: So in other words, everyone can be in back or front?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Note that this has nothing to do with linear algebra.  Also, the rules are unclear.  What does, say, "Mom and sister in front or back" mean?  Does that mean they must both be front or both in back?  Something else?  The header says "no restrictions" , is that what you meant?